# Calculating the 2D mean of a 3D jagged NumPy Array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, mean, exponent, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to calculate the Hurst Exponent of a time series in python, a value that determines some mean reversion characteristics of a time series for quantitative finance. I've taken a time series, of any length, and chosen to split it into chunks of data, a process that is a part of calculating the Hurst Exponent (one of several methods). I'm writing this as a function. Imagine I have the time series (prices of a security) as "y" and the number of chunks I want as "n":

```
def hurst(y,n):

     y = array_split(y,n)
```

The problem is that now the array is split into chunks, where one of the chunks is not equal in size with the others. I want to find the mean, standard deviation, mean centered series, cumulative sum of the mean centered series, and range of the cumulative sum for each chunk. But since the array is not uniform in size, I haven't found a way to accomplish this. Basically when I try to pass

```
mean(y,axis=0)
```

Or 1 or 2, for the axis, I get an error. When using n=20, the shape of the array is given as

```
(20,)
```

I thought maybe "vectorize" could help me? But I haven't quite figured how to use it. I'm trying to avoid looping through the data.

Sample Data after it is split:

```
[array([[ 1.04676],
   [ 1.0366 ],
   [ 1.0418 ],
   [ 1.0536 ],
   [ 1.0639 ],
   [ 1.06556],
   [ 1.0668 ]]), array([[ 1.056  ],
   [ 1.053  ],
   [ 1.0521 ],
   [ 1.0517 ],
   [ 1.0551 ],
   [ 1.0485 ],
   [ 1.05705]]), array([[ 1.0531],
   [ 1.0545],
   [ 1.0682],
   [ 1.08  ],
   [ 1.0728],
   [ 1.061 ],
   [ 1.0554]]), array([[ 1.0642],
   [ 1.0607],
   [ 1.0546],
   [ 1.0521],
   [ 1.0548],
   [ 1.0647],
   [ 1.0604]])
```

Data type `list`

Comment: What type is `y`? Please provide an example of simple data

Comment: `y` starts as a Pandas dataframe. Then I'm using `as_matrix` to get it into an array form. Then I'm using 'array_split' on it. I guess the final form is `list`. I'm very new to python

Comment: If you want to know the type of a variable `a` you can use `print(type(a))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a list of averages you can simply use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
    [mean(x[axis]) for axis in range(len(x))]
```

it goes over the axes and compute the mean of each part.

Comment: I tried this, however am I correct that it only returns the mean of the indexed chunk? In this case it only returns one value for the chunk with 0 index? I need the mean of every chunk, in list form.

Comment: @user22393 I change that for you. But you really need to be aware of what type you are using

Comment: it is essential that I split the data into chunks that may not be equal depending on the total length of the time series. Is a better way to split the data into uneven chunks than `array_split` that yields the `list` type?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that stumbles across this, I've solved the problem and resolved to using a Pandas Dataframe instead...

```
def hurst(y,n):

y = prices.as_matrix()
y = array_split(y,n)
y = pd.DataFrame.from_records(y).transpose()
y = y.dropna()

# Mean Centered Series

m = y.mean(axis='columns')

Y = y.sub(m,axis = 'rows')


# Standard Deviation of Series

S = y.std(axis='columns')

# Cumulative Sum Series

Z = Y.cumsum()

# Range Series

R = Z.max(axis='columns')-Z.min(axis='columns')

# Rescale Range

RS = R/S
RS = RS.sort_values()

# Time Period

s = shape(y)

t = linspace(1,s[0],s[0])

# Log Scales

logt = log10(t)
logRS = log10(RS)

print len(t),len(logRS)

# Regression Fit

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.mstats.linregress(logt, logRS)

# Hurst Exponent

H = slope/2

return H, logt, logRS
```